# CoreData Edit Row

Tags: swift, core-data

Trying to implement core data edit record. 
Current Status : In the view did Load I have aded

```
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
```

The edit button is appeared on the top left navigation bar. By clicking the edit button the red busy icons are appearing. if I click the icon then delete button appears. When I click the table view cell then nothing happens.
Desired Response: I want to call the edit table view controller so that the record can be edited. 
I have added didSelect but it is only being called when the table view is not in edit mode. 
How to call the edit view controller if I tap any table view cell with the edit icon appearing on the left side. 
For example in the clock app. When you click the edit button the red icons appeared on the left side. If we want to edit the time then we can tap the table view cell i.e. alarm time and a view is posed up to edit the time. Same functionality is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the didSelectRowAtIndexPath to work during editing, you have to set the **allowsSelectionDuringEditing** to **true**

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It worked well for me
inside CellForRowAt I have now added
 tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
then inside didSelect. I have tracked it by adding 
 if (tableView.isEditing){
         // code for editing the Row
        }